# date selected from datepicker

Tags: cocoa

Sir,i want to pass the selected date from datepicker to the textbox.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the date selected in the DatePicker, format it, and write it out:

`NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSDate *pickedDate = [datePicker date];
customDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pickedDate];
[dateFormatter release];`

Apple has a doc on [different date formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

You can trigger the change by hooking into the `valueChanged` event of the DatePicker